# Figma Drop Shadow In Android

Tags: android, colors, shadow, direction, dropshadow

I have one figma file in which component have property of Drop Shadow, I coundn't find a way to replacate the same. Is there any library to get exact same amount of shadow which figma have.

[image: Figma component]
[image: Also I have 2 drop shadow in one component] 
[image: Drop shadow-1]
[image: Drop shadow-2]

I want attribute like X shadow, Y shadow, blur, spread, shadow color.

I tried
`com.github.BluRe-CN:ComplexView:1.1`
and few custom drawble but not getting same results.

I want multiple/single drop shadow on button or cardview also want property like X shadow, Y shadow, blur, spread, shadow color.